about greenfoot racing game. how to stop the game when one actor finished
how to stop all actors if one actor reach the edge of the world. send help beginner only my prof doesn't teach. ty
to stop the game when an actor reach the finish line please send help I'm just learning still and please explain why it work that way because I want to understand how it work so that I will know how to do it next time

What does "stop" entail for you?  How to "stop" the game is entirely dependent on your game loop. You'll need to provide more details about this

According to the documentation the class Greenfoot has the class method stop() that stops the scenario (same as clicking the "Pause" button):
    // your condition...
    Greenfoot.stop();


Wouldn't that "freeze" the entire game then?

@DarkBee Sure. As a voluntary teacher in a high school this is the common goal.

I see. I thought the situation to be more in-depth, e.g. stop the game loop, show a scoreboard and ability to restart the game loop.
